# Configuring AWS with Asp.net maintining sessions and implimenting SSO

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cognito, identity

I have created user pool and configured with asp.net core API that communicates with AWS for Login/signup etc.

I have three stand alone applications build in asp.net I want to integrate these application with AWS through that API.

API is working fine that is able to sign in, signup, forgot password, reset password password etc. **but how can** I maintain the session(identity) in my all three applications and i also want to implement Single Sign On (SSO).

I am using AWS SDK along with libraries:
Amazon.AspNetCore.Identity.Cognito;
Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication;

Answer (score 0):

are they web apps? if yes, your browser will maintain the session with Amazon Cognito.

Comment: Yes these all are web apps but how can browser store session in all of them , I just logged into a API ?